# Turning a subset based on multiple parameters into a looping function

Tags: r, function, parameters, subset, cbind

I have a dataframe with 3000+ items (each row is a new item with the item_id in the first column) with 2500+ attributes in each subsequent column.

```
item_id    attribute_1    attribute_2 ... category_1 ... category_2
x3902      1              5               1              0
x1402      2              0               1              1
```

I am able to successfully grab a random list of 10 items that fulfil a given attribute and category:

```
subset_of_items = sample(subset(df$item_id, (df$attribute1 == 3 & df$category_2 == 1 )),10)
```

I need to repeat this for 30+ combinations of attribute + category. So I was hoping to create a function that loops and saves the output into a table where each table column is a list of 10 items that fulfils a set of conditions.

This is as far as I could get, but can't get it to successfully run:

```
df <- read.csv ("data.csv",sep=",")

attribute <- c("attribute_1", "attribute_2", "attribute_3")
value <- c(1, 2, 5)
category <- c("category_1", "category_1", "category_2")

function1 <- function(x, attribute_x, value_x, category_x)
{
  dftemp = subset(x[["item_id"]], (x[[attribute_x]] == value_x & x[[category_x]] == 1 ))
  output <- cbind(output, dftemp)
}

function1(df, attribute, value, category)
```

The cherry on the cake would be to name each of the columns as `attribute_x` .

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Can you provide some data to work with? Suggestion: you canedit the post by adding the output of `dput()` applied to (a subset of) your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following (this uses a data.table approach)

1. Set your df to data.table

```
library(data.table)
df <- read.csv("data.csv",sep=",")
setDT(df)
```

2. Make a revised function, called `get_subset()` that returns a vector of item_ids that meet the attribute and category requirements, using `get()`. It
   also checks if you have `size` items return, and pads with `as.character(NA)`  to ensure that the returned vector has length = `size`

```
get_subset <- function(x, attribute_x, value_x, category_x, size=10)
{
  subset = x[get(attribute_x)==value_x & get(category_x) == 1, .(item_id)] %>% 
    .[sample(1:.N, size=min(size, .N)), item_id]
  if(length(subset)<size) subset=c(subset,rep(as.character(NA),size-length(subset)))
  return(subset)
}
```

3. Put your combinations of interest into a small data.table

```
combinations = data.table(
  attribute = c("attribute_1", "attribute_2"),
  value = c(1, 5),
  category = c("category_1", "category_2")
)
```

4. use `lapply`, to loop over the rows of your combinations, each time feeding the attribute, value, and category value of the combination to the get_subset function

```
result = lapply(seq(1,nrow(combinations)), function(i) {
    items = data.table(get_subset(
      x=df,
      attribute_x = combinations[i,attribute],
      value_x = combinations[i,value],
      category_x = combinations[i, category],
      size=10))
    setNames(items, combinations[i,attribute])
})
```

That returns a list of data.tables with a single column, that is named after the attribute for that contribution

5. Use `do.call` with cbind to bind them into a single data.table

```
result = do.call(cbind, result)
```

If this is your original `df`

```
df = data.table(
  item_id = paste0("x", stringr::str_pad(sample(1:1000,100),width = 4,side = "left",pad = "0")),
  attribute_1=sample(1:10, 100, replace=T),
  attribute_2=sample(1:10, 100, replace=T),
  category_1=sample(c(0,1),100, replace=T),
  category_2=sample(c(0,1),100, replace=T)
)
```

then the above `combinations`, will return something like the following in `result` (Note, that my df example uses sample without seed, so your results will differ)

```
    attribute_1 attribute_2
 1:       x7511       x7302
 2:       x0325       x0956
 3:       x6748       x1893
 4:       x4462       x6958
 5:       x4146        <NA>
 6:       x5407        <NA>
 7:        <NA>        <NA>
 8:        <NA>        <NA>
 9:        <NA>        <NA>
10:        <NA>        <NA>
```

Comment: Incredible, this is EXACTLY what I was trying to accomplish. Worked like an absolute charm. Thank you!